# Inheritance of constructor

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-721

Why does warning appear with inheritance of constructor?

```
contract MyToken is ERC721Token{
function MyToken(string _name, string _symbol) ERC721Token(_name, _symbol) public {
}
```

The content of the warning is

> zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol:38:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use
>    "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
>     function ERC721Token(string _name, string _symbol) public {
>     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
>   ,/C/twork/702_Ethereum/ERC-OPZ/myERC721/contracts/MyToken.sol:8:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated.
>    Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
>     function MyToken(string _name, string _symbol) ERC721Token(_name, _symbol) public {
>     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

I am using truffle v4.1.7 
           solidity v0.4.23

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the version 0.4.22 of Solidity, you don't define the constructor as the function with the same name than the contract, you have to use `constructor(myparams....) {...}` from now on.

Read more [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22).